# Custom Save button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview

my question is simple, how do i create a custom save and update button for records entered in a detail view. I dont want to use the ones given. thanks a lot.

Comment: i tried adding the CommandName on my image buttons .. like Insert etc. but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. One is the `OnItemCommand` and you'll roll your own commands. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand.aspx

The easier way is to use the `OnItemInserted` and `OnItemUpdating` events. Just send the *Insert* or *Update* commands instead as appropriate and you can use easier `EventArgs`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserting.aspx
<http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemupdating.aspx

From these pages, basically what you'll do is capture a command from a button in your `DetailsView`.

**Custom "Add" commamnd with ItemCommand**

```
Sub CustomerDetailView_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)

    ' Use the CommandName property to determine which button
    ' was clicked. 
    If e.CommandName = "Add" Then
        ' Do your work here if Add Contact is clicked
    End If
End Sub
```

**Easier built in Insert command with ItemInserting**

```
Sub CustomerDetailView_ItemInserting((ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DetailsViewInsertEventArgs)
    ' Access the actual rows with
    Some variable1 = e.Values("CustomerID")
    Some variable2 = e.Values("CompanyName")
    Some variable3 = e.Values("City")

    ' Do something with them
End Sub
```

**Code front**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="CustomerDetailView" 
    DataSourceID="DetailsViewSource"
    AutoGenerateRows="false" 
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" 
    AllowPaging="true" 
    OnItemCommand="CustomerDetailView_ItemCommand"
    OnItemInserting="CustomerDetailView_ItemInserting"
    OnItemUpdating="CustomerDetailView_ItemUpdating"
    runat="server">
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="Navy" ForeColor="White" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Store ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Store Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btAddContact" runat="server" Text="Add Contact" CommandName="Add" />
                            Or
                <asp:Button ID="btAddContact" runat="server" Text="Add Contact" CommandName="Insert" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btAddContact" runat="server" Text="Save Contact" CommandName="Update" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any button that implements the `IButtonControl` interface. The key is to set the CommandName correctly. Hopefully this will give you the freedom to style your button the way you need to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx

You can find a list of the relevant command names here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ... CommandName="Save" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ... CommandName="Update" />
```

Comment: does this work for a details view .. coz i am trying it and the page just refreshes but nothing is updated.